# Configuring Eclipse CDT for Apache Mesos

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, mesos

How do I configure Eclipse CDT Luna to work with Apache Mesos directly?

The steps for building Apache Mesos on a Linux machine are known and provided here:
http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This works on a Mac with Eclipse “Kepler”. I hope it is similar on other platform variants.)

1. Install Eclipse with CDT
2. “git clone” a Mesos git repository into a local directory as described in the “Getting started” guide you referenced.
3. Open eclipse. Select “File->Import…->Git->Projects from Git”.
4. Select “Existing local repository”.
5. Click on “Add…” and add your local Mesos git directory. It will show up in the list in the selector box from step 4.
6. Select the entry for your directory and click on “Next”.
7. Select “Import as general project” and click on “Next”..
8. Give your project a name and click on “Finish”. Now you have a project.
9. Make sure you are in the C++ perspective. Select/highlight your project in the Project Explorer. Then select “File->New…->Convert to a C/C++ Autotools project”.
10. Edit your project’s properties (Select project, Cmd-I). On the pane “C/C++ Build”, add “/build” to the value of “Build directory”. It should look like this: ${workspace_loc:/myProjectName}/build
11. Optional: In pane “Autotools” go to “Configure Settings->Advanced”. Under “Additional command line options” you can put “--disable-python --disable-java” if you don’t want to build Python and Java-related stuff every time.

—

As a prerequisite, I am using these values in my eclipse.ini (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini):

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx6144m

Comment: Eclipse plugins used:

Comment: Eclipse plugin used:
http://eclipse.org/egit
(“Linux Tools”, which contain “Automake” should come with CDT now.)

Beneficial:
Set editors so that TAB gets replaced by spaces.
Set autoindent to 2 or 4 spaces (Mesos uses both).

In Preferences, under “C/C++->Indexer”, use large values for “Cache limits”. I have: 50%, 1024, 1024.